# Can I connect power supplies to each end of an LED strip?

Tags: lighting

I want to run 45 feet of [this product](http://m.ebay.com/itm/2-5M-RGB-5050-Waterproof-LED-Strip-light-300-44-Key-Remote-3A-12V-Supply-Power-/302005606197?_trkparms=aid%253D222007%2526algo%253DSIC.MBE%2526ao%253D1%2526asc%253D20150519202348%2526meid%253Db076e7e0925b46afae66ca1594591b2d%2526pid%253D100408%2526rk%253D7%2526rkt%253D25%2526mehot%253Dag%2526sd%253D381714800631&_trksid=p2056116.c100408.m2460) and run them daisy chain style ( 2 5m reels with a 9 foot piece in the center) and put a controller and power supply on both ends. Would that be possible?

Comment: What do you mean by a "power supply on both ends" ? Do you understand how electrical power operates, and do you recognize the amperage required to operate a string?

Comment: This really doesn't seem like a "Home Improvement" question. Can you please rephrase the question to detail what you are trying to accomplish? Also, I highly suggest you check out some LED strip tutorials. Adafruit and Sparkfun are two sites with vast education sections for you to get familiar with LED lighting.

Comment: I would suggest you ask the seller.

Comment: This is a pile of random parts.  They won't work together.   They can't be daisy chained or extended in the way you want.  What you want is possible for a few dollars more, but you need different stuff.  @HariGanti incorrect, this is precisely for DIY home improvement, note the 120V plugs.  Used on vehicles yes, but not 45' of it unless you own a British narrowboat or work for Boeing.

Comment: Although this could be a home improvement check out the tutorials on led's as @HariGanti suggests. Some power supplies can be run in parallel to increase the current but many should not be connected in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Basics

A 12-volt, 300-LED 5050 strip needs 6 amps, or 2 amps per RGB channel.   That's 72W.

DC power supplies can be ganged in parallel if they're  of any quality.

On an interconnected system, there must be only one controller, period.

A system can be of any size, if extended by amplifiers and/or feeders.  So if you want to put mood lighting on the USS Intrepid, good news.

Amplifiers take the output of the one controller and use its signal to drive more strips.  This is used if the strip load exceeds the controller's capacity, or if you want/need to use multiple power supplies.

Everything I said above applies to the eBay cheapies. You don't need to go to exotica for any of it.

### That kit is random leftovers

The stuff isn't even meant to work together. Obviously they're supplying 3A power supplies with 6A LED strips. That's why it's dimming out on you.   If you ganged both dc power supplies, you might have enough power to operate one 5m spool properly.

You assumed  it would work together merely because it was sold together.  Nope, those people do not care.  You have to watch your wallet when dealing with that bunch.

That said, you did not get ripped off.  The parts you *can* use, 2 reels and 1 controller, are worth the price on your link.

### What you really need

Your 45’ loop will take almost all of 3 whole 5m/16' strips, or 18A, or 216W.  Per RGB channel, 6A or 72W per channel.

You will not find a controller that can drive 216W.   However, you can have the controller drive amplifier(s).  You can obtain a single amplifier that can drive 216W.  Or you can segment the strip and drive it with many smaller amplifiers, driven by multiple power supplies (or one), which may be easier to hook up.

You cannot drive 3 strips from one end.  The internal "wires" (PC traces) inside the strip cannot carry enough current to power more than *barely* 2 strips (10m) and even then, they will "dim" dreadfully down their length.

If you are seeing dimming down even one 5m strip, I would not be surprised.  Passing 6A (round trip) is a lot for those narrow PC traces. In that case, either split the strip or feed it from both ends.

### Option 1: big power supply, 1 amplifier, feeder

Here you use at least a 300W DC power supply and the controller feeds one big amplifier.   The internal PC board traces on the strips can't handle nearly that much power, so you run parallel feeder wire.  This is 4 wires (RGB and common) that run parallel to the LED strips and tie back into it wherever feasible.  At the least I'd feed each end of each strip.

### Option 2: split the strips and use smaller amplifiers

I notice they make some very inexpensive amplifiers with 4A rating.  That can comfortably power half a 5m strip, so you would cut the strips.   You would need to feed each amplifier from the one controller.  Each amplifier could be powered from its own power supply, or from the same supply, or any mix you please. For instance you could use two of those 3A supplies you have to power two half-strips, and then power the rest from a single larger supply.

Comment: Ty Harper  that's what I need to know

Answer (score 1):

**Given the style of controller, you *cannot* simply put power supplies with controllers on each end**

**Do not try this**

Now that we've gotten that out of the way, let's go over some basics of LED strips.

**LEDs**

In general, SMD LEDs, like the 5050 LEDs used on this strip, operate around 4V with a series resistor that limits current to ~20mA. Because these are RGB LEDs, this means 20mA *per color*, so up to 60mA per LED. It's possible to connect the LEDs in series (in sets of three, usually) so the total voltage drop across them is just under 12V. This is done to minimize current requirements by increasing the voltage requirement instead. It makes things more efficient.

**Power Supply**

The power supply specifies that its a 12V power supply, with a 3A maximum current. The strip says it has 300 individual 5050 LEDs on it. We divide that by 3 because every 3 LEDs are in series, with each grouping in parallel with the others.

```
300 / 3 = 100
```

That should have been obvious, but this means that we have 100 sets of LEDs, each able to draw up to 60mA per set. Some more math:

```
100 * .06mA = 6A
```

Theoretically, you would need a 6A power supply (minimum) just to power one strip to full brightness. It *is* possible that these LEDs run lower currents than 20mA, but 20mA is pretty standard, so I doubt these are any different.

**Controller**

If you look at the pictures, there are 4 wires: Red, Green, Blue, and White. Whether common anode or common cathode, the point is that the white wire is shared as either a supply or sink wire for the red, green, and blue wires, each of which is connected to its respective color channel.

I have no doubt that this is an analog system, meaning that the controller works by limiting current on the red wire to dim the red color channel on *all* the LEDs. The same happens for the blue and green channels.

**Combined**

Putting it all together, this means that two strips (not including that additional 9' section) could draw up to 12A @ 12V.

You can only have one controller attached because the controller controls current on the red, green, and blue wires. Two controllers would "fight" each other, creating short circuits where one tries to source a certain amount of current while the other sinks it, and the LEDs get no power because that's the high-resistance pathway.

Lastly, the included power supply itself might not be powerful enough for the LEDs at full brightness.

**Suggestions**

Aside from my earlier comment to learn more about LEDs, there are ways in which you *could* do this.

1. If you are dead-set on using the product you linked to, just make sure that the two strips are not connected to each other. You might still have issues with an undersized power supply, but it might work well enough.
2. If you do some research, you can find analog power stips without power supplies or controllers. You can then calculate the power requirements (or read the datasheet, which good sellers will provide) to find a suitable power supply and a controller for it.
3. If you're willing to spend a fair bit more money, you can get a digitally controlled system (search WS2812B) with a controller. This will even let you adjust individual LEDs, rather than the whole strip, which is probably overkill. What it does enable, however, is for you to connect two smaller power supplies to each end of the strip. This is advantageous because it minimizes voltage drop across the massive length of the stip. It's like water pressure. If you have a bunch of upstream faucets open, the ones further down the line don't get as much pressure, or voltage in this case. A power supply at each end helps mitigate the problem. Because each LED has a microchip on its die to regulate it, you don't have controllers "fighting" each other, so it works.

Either way, more research, and a willingness to spend a bit more money to get quality equipment will go a long way.

Comment: Ty for your input Hari Ganti I might be contacting you in the future for more advice if that's okay. The reason why I ask if I can put a controller and a power supply on either end because voltage dropping that I'm getting in the leds. I was not for sure if I could do that or not without burning up anything including my house. What I'm gonna do with it is put it inside of a bedroom its a gaming room for my son. What i was trying to find out is if I could connect two 5 meter reels of led light strips and connect the 9-foot piece with non solder connector Clips in the center and then hook up the

Comment: power supply on either end with the controller but only use one of the RF eyes so it didn't try to pick up same time as the other one if that makes any sense. Sorry for the dumb question just trying to understand a little better. And I have already purchased the product already I thought it was going to be a simple cool thing to add to his room.

Comment: We can certainly chat more. I'm happy to help, but I still highly recommend some of the tutorials from good electronics suppliers. They're typically very thorough and will help you understand the different options available (as well as how to construct your own system).